How to specify different output formats for multiple entries in Vite
I'm working on a Chrome extension using Vite, and I need to specify different output formats for different entry points:

The ./src/content.ts entry should output in iife format.
The other entries (e.g., ./src/background.ts, ./index.html) should output in es format.

However, I get the following error:
Invalid value for option "output.inlineDynamicImports" - multiple inputs are not supported when "output.inlineDynamicImports" is true.

After researching, I found that creating separate Vite config files is one solution, but I wonder if there is a cleaner way to achieve this without needing multiple config files.
Here is my current Vite config:
export default defineConfig({
  ...
  build: {
    outDir: 'build',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        content: './src/content.ts',
        background: './src/background.ts',
        main: './index.html',
      },
      output: [
        {
          name: 'content',
          format: 'iife',
          entryFileNames: "[name].js",
        },
        {
          format: 'es',
          entryFileNames: "[name].js",
          globals: {
            react: 'React',
          },
        },
      ]
    },
   
  },
});



Thanks

Check this once https://github.com/trouni/chrome-extension-vue3-boilerplate, Perhaps you can follow the same approach, Separate vite config for content and rest of the scripts

@Vikas thank you, it looks great,
I will thoroughly study this project.

Welcome Mate!! LMK if you need any help!
